# Aggregator of type top_hits cannot accept sub-aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to execute below query but getting Aggregator [recommendationIds] of type [top_hits] cannot accept sub-aggregations below is the query and corresponding java code and i am using java rest high level client for elastic search client i have tried multiple time by placing a top aggregation in several places but it is not working.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "id.keyword": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "shipmentId.keyword": [
                            "123"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "exceptionId.keyword": {
                            "value": [
                                "1",
                                "2"
                            ],
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "recommendationIds": {
            "top_hits": {
                "from": 0,
                "size": 1,
                "version": false,
                "explain": false,
                "_source": {
                    "includes": [
                        "id"
                    ],
                    "excludes": [
                        ""
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "by_item": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "item.keyword",
                        "size": 10,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                            {
                                "_count": "desc"
                            },
                            {
                                "_key": "asc"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "by_destination": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "destinationLocation.keyword",
                                "size": 10,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [
                                    {
                                        "_count": "desc"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_key": "asc"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "aggregations": {
                                "by_trans": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "transportMode.keyword",
                                        "size": 10,
                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                        "order": [
                                            {
                                                "_count": "desc"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_key": "asc"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "aggregations": {
                                        "by_sourcelocation": {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "field": "sourceLocation.keyword",
                                                "size": 10,
                                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                "order": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_count": "desc"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "_key": "asc"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "aggregations": {
                                                "by_shipdate": {
                                                    "terms": {
                                                        "field": "shipDate",
                                                        "size": 10,
                                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                        "order": [
                                                            {
                                                                "_count": "desc"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "_key": "asc"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "aggregations": {
                                                        "by_arrival": {
                                                            "terms": {
                                                                "field": "arrivalDate",
                                                                "size": 10,
                                                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                                "order": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "_count": "desc"
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "_key": "asc"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            "aggregations": {
                                                                "quantity": {
                                                                    "sum": {
                                                                        "field": "transferQuantity"
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "transfercost": {
                                                                    "sum": {
                                                                        "field": "transferCost"
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "revenueRecovered": {
                                                                    "sum": {
                                                                        "field": "revenueRecovered"
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the java code to generate the query:

```
List<String> excludeRecommendationIds = Stream.of("")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        BoolQueryBuilder mustNotMatchRecommendationIds =
                QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("shipmentId.keyword", asList("123")))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("exceptionId.keyword", asList("1", "2")))
                        .mustNot(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("id.keyword", excludeRecommendationIds))
                        .minimumShouldMatch(1);

        TopHitsAggregationBuilder topHitsAggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
                .topHits("recommendationIds")
                .fetchSource("id", "")
                .size(1);


        AggregationBuilder itemAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_item").field("item.keyword");

        AggregationBuilder destinationAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_destination").field("destinationLocation.keyword");

        AggregationBuilder transportAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_trans").field("transportMode.keyword");

        AggregationBuilder sourceAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_sourcelocation").field("sourceLocation.keyword");

        AggregationBuilder shipDateAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_shipdate").field("shipDate");

        AggregationBuilder arrivalDateAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_arrival").field("arrivalDate");

        AggregationBuilder quantityAgg = AggregationBuilders.sum("quantity").field("transferQuantity");
        AggregationBuilder transferCostAgg = AggregationBuilders.sum("transfercost").field("transferCost");
        AggregationBuilder revenueRecoveredAgg = AggregationBuilders.sum("revenueRecovered").field("revenueRecovered");


        AggregationBuilder aggregation = itemAgg.subAggregation(destinationAgg
                .subAggregation(transportAgg.subAggregation(sourceAgg.subAggregation(shipDateAgg.subAggregation(arrivalDateAgg.subAggregation(
                        quantityAgg).subAggregation(transferCostAgg).subAggregation(revenueRecoveredAgg))))));

        topHitsAggregationBuilder.subAggregation(aggregation);

        //searchSourceBuilder.size(0);
        searchSourceBuilder.query(mustNotMatchRecommendationIds);
        searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. Since your top-hits are only used to retrieve the `id`, how about using a `terms` agg instead? That one *can* accept sub-aggs:

```
...
  "aggregations": {
    "recommendationIds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "by_item": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "item
...
```